# kivy - Style Dynamic Objects - bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, styles, kivy

I have the followig code:

```html
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class Divs(App):
    def build(self):
   b = BoxLayout()
   t = TextInput(text='hello world',
  font_size=10)
   b.add_widget(t)
      return b



if __name__ == "__main__":
    Divs().run()
```

The Text Input is really awful.
How can I add style? Is there a possibility to add like bootstrap css or is there a default stylesheet that is better than this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can create a subclass of `TextInput` and manipulate its properties, draw on its canvas, add animations, etc.

If you would like to quickly add to your project a stylish text input, then I would suggest taking a look at [KivyMD](https://gitlab.com/kivymd/KivyMD), which mimics google's Material Design. You can also peek inside the into [code](https://gitlab.com/kivymd/KivyMD/blob/master/kivymd/textfields.py) and see how the author implemented it.

*The project is in early alpha, so the only documentation is inside source code. A presentation is in the `kitchen_sink.py` file.*